# Loading treebank corpus with brown's tagset

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk, corpus, tagged-corpus

I have a WSJ treebank corpus from nltk. I want to load it with the tagset of brown corpus. Is it possible?

```
import nltk
wsj = nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_sents(tagset ='universal') # universal tags
wsj2 = nltk.corpus.treebank.tagged_sents() # treebank specific tags
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the discussion in this [thread](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/483#issuecomment-74781594) it is not possible.

So far NLTK only provides the possibility to map specific tagsets to the universal tagset.
Maybe one of the suggested solutions in the discussion can help:

> This is apparently not supported in NLTK yet, but see Dan Zeman's Interset tool or my script at https://gist.github.com/nschneid/6476715